# I can not login wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am trying to open admin panel of wordpress site, but it is showing error on laptop while it is opening on mobile very easily. I can't understand what's going wrong. Can anybody help me out?

This site can’t be reached
The [webpage](http://dailycricketupdates.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdailycricketupdates.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost-new.php&reauth=1) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

> ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Comment: which operating system and browser you use ?

Comment: check that 
https://superuser.com/questions/893908/err-invalid-chunked-encoding-from-chrome